# Ember-CLI -> Heroku Deployment - Cannot access public/ folder

Tags: heroku, ember.js, ember-cli, heroku-toolbelt

I was able to successfully deploy my Ember application via the buildpack suggested in the documentation. However for some reason, while the application works fine, the public/ folder and all sub-directories are giving me 403 errors. When the image is direct-linked, it gives a 404. I did a CHMOD to 777 on all contents and still is giving me errors.

Is there something that has to be done for heroku configuration in order to view the public folder properly? It works on my localhost.

Using Ember-CLI with Heroku CLI and tonycoco's buildpack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out a while back, in case anyone wants to know it's because Ember-CLI's fingerprinting conflicting with direct-linking the images.

Adding this in Brocfile.js:

```
fingerprint: {
    exclude: ['assets/images']
}
```

Allows the filed to be direct-linked. See [the ember-cli documentation](http://www.ember-cli.com/#fingerprinting-and-cdn-urls) for more details.

Comment: Here is the updated link to the ember-cli documentation since that link is broken: http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#fingerprinting-and-cdn-urls